# Adding multiple rows into an existing table via VBA / button with the ability to repeat as needed

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have been piecemealing code based on internet research.

I am attempting to add a row to the table (with a button).

- I am looking to add the row between Rows 6 and 7 so the user could add location 4-1, 5-1 etc.
- After the row is added I want the same formatting applied (all outlines) and the formulas in the non-highlighted columns to be carried over as well into the newly created row.
- From my understanding the way I have the SUM formula at the bottom of the table it should automatically expand itself to account for the newly added rows.
- If it assists with an example, the name of this table is "Prop_Exp".
- The code I have will work on one instance, but within the same workbook I need to create other "add row" buttons for various classes of business. The references end up being shifted based on if any rows were added in the preceding sections.
- All tables have a uniform number of columns and formulas so I feel its a matter of finding the bottommost row in the table based on finding the word total (or other metric) and then from that reference point adding a row based on offset and then copy/paste from there (again with offset).

[image: Spreadsheet In Question]

#### What I have tried

My gut reaction was to include the information within various tabs so there would be only one "total" row. And I could Ctrl+Down Arrow to find the bottom, but then I realized that as data is added the Ctrl+Down will no longer function as intended as the command will find the bottom in any data entered and throw off the reference point.

```vb
Sub Add_Prop_Row()
'
' Add_Prop_Row Macro
'

'
    Range("B1").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    Selection.Offset(-3, 0).Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Insert , CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    Range(Cells(Selection.Row, 3), Cells(Selection.Row, 10)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range(ActiveCell.Offset(-2, 0), ActiveCell.Offset(-2, 0)).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats, Operation:= _
        xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("C1").Select
End Sub
```

I searched for a way to reference the word "total" in a table. Thought process was once I could find the word "total" I could use offset from there, and if need be find a way to loop the command to keep finding it as a reference, but the match formula is giving me an error.

```vb
Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro
'

ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Prop_Exp").Range.Select
.Formula = Match(Total, $A:$A,0)
'
End Sub
```

Comment: What have you tried after doing your research? Where did you run into problems? Please include that in your question.

Comment: not sure if I need to comment for you to see it's been updated, but added what I have done. can expand on anything else as needed.